# What is the fastest way to generate all subarrays of a given array in less than O(n^2)?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I want to generate all possible sub arrays in an array. I have tried an algorithm whose complexity is O(n^2).

```
    for(i=1;i<=N;++i){
    if(S[i]==k)
      return 1;
    x=S[i];
    for(j=i+1;j<=N;++j){
        x^=S[j];
        if(x==k)
          return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are n^2 possible subarrays in an array of size n. You cannot generate output of size n^2 in less than O(n^2) time.

Comment: not to mention the O(n) time needed to copy each array

Comment: @spug: This can be cured, actually, if you arrange for your sub-arrays to be backed by the original array -- e.g. `subList`-s of an `ArrayList` in Java, (pointer, length) pairs in C.

Answer (score 0):

From the code it looks like your function is trying to:

> Return 1 if there is a sub-array that XORs to a target value k, otherwise 0.

A more efficient approach to solve this is described on [geeksforgeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-number-subarrays-given-xor/):

> An Efficient Solution solves the above problem in O(n) time. Let us call the XOR of all elements in the range [i+1, j] as A, in the range [0,i] as B, and in the range [0,j] as C. If we do XOR of B with C, the overlapping elements in [0,i] from B and C zero out and we get XOR of all elements in the range [i+1,j], i.e. A. Since A = B XOR C, we have B = A XOR C. Now, if we know the value of C and we take the value of A as m, we get the count of A as the count of all B satisfying this relation. Essentially, we get the count of all subarrays having XOR-sum m for each C. As we take sum of this count over all C, we get our answer.

The code there actually goes a bit further and returns the total number of sub-arrays that have the target value, but you can convert it to match your problem by returning 1 if the count is greater than 0.

Comment: I saw the code on geeksforgeeks but I'm not able to understand the logic there. Can you please exlain me the logic behind it?